# Express Router render and public static files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, express

I have the following code in `index.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var PORT    = 3000;
var routes = require('./scripts/routes/routes');

app.set('views', './views');

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('App running');
});
```

In my `routes.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  request('https://www.reddit.com/r/earthporn.json', function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(body);
      var items = data['data']['children'];
      var urls = items.map(function(item) {
        item_data = item['data'];
        item_preview = item_data['preview'];
        item_images = item_preview['images'];
        return item_images.map(function(image) {
          return image['source']['url'];
        });
      });

      res.render('index', { subReddit: 'earthporn', images: urls });
    }
  });
});

router.get('/subreddit/:subreddit', function (req, res) {
  var subreddit = '/r/' + req.params['subreddit'];
  request('https://www.reddit.com'+ subreddit +'.json', function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(body);
      var items = data['data']['children'];
      var urls = items.map(function(item) {
        item_data = item['data'];
        item_preview = item_data['preview'];
        item_images = item_preview['images'];
        return item_images.map(function(image) {
          return image['source']['url'];
        });
      });

      res.render('index', { subReddit: subreddit, images: urls });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

In my `views/index.pug`:

```
html
  head
    link(href='app.css' rel="stylesheet")
    title Hello World!
  body
    div(class="container")
      h1= subReddit

      div(class="images_gird")
        each url in images
          div(class="image", style="background-image: url('"+ url +"')")
```

In my browser, if I access `localhost:3000`, everything works correctly, I see a list of images from the subreddit `earthporn`.

However, if I access `localhost:3000/subreddit/cute`, for example, I get this in the logs:

```
express:router dispatching GET /subreddit/cute +2s
  express:router query  : /subreddit/cute +1ms
  express:router expressInit  : /subreddit/cute +1ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /subreddit/cute +0ms
  express:router router  : /subreddit/cute +5ms
  express:router dispatching GET /subreddit/cute +0ms
  express:view lookup "index.pug" +4s
  express:view stat ".../views/index.pug" +0ms
  express:view render ".../views/index.pug" +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /subreddit/app.css +83ms !! <<--- Why is this happening?
  express:router query  : /subreddit/app.css +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /subreddit/app.css +1ms
  express:router serveStatic  : /subreddit/app.css +0ms
  express:router router  : /subreddit/app.css +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /subreddit/app.css +1ms
```

This is preventing me from rendering the images of the subreddit that the user enters in the URL. I don't know why on earth is express receiving a request with `subreddit/app.css` , doesn't make any sense.

In the network tab, in Chrome, when I enter `localhost:3000/subreddit/cute` I do see two requests:

`GET http://localhost:3000/subreddit/cute`
And right after
`GET http://localhost:3000/subreddit/app.css`

So maybe this is a problem in chrome, I really don't understand. For the request `localhost:3000` , everything works fine and just one request made.

Comment: I assume because `index.pug` has -> `link(href='app.css' rel="stylesheet")`

Comment: are you getting the data on server side ?

Comment: Yes I do get the data. I just checked and actually, for the first request (the one that works correctly), I do see a GET app.css, but it doesn't block the rendering of the images. It only blocks the rendering in the second request

Comment: `link(href='app.css' rel="stylesheet")`  from your route this is going to be looking for a file in your public folder called  `/subreddit/app.css` is that what you want..  I'd assume you want `link(href='/app.css' rel="stylesheet")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
express:router dispatching GET /subreddit/app.css +83ms
```

is trying to request https://www.reddit.com'+ app.css +'.json'
which is wrong so it is taking so long.

In index.pug try putting full url for app.css

Comment: How would I put the full URL for the css file? I'm serving the static files directly from my `public` folder, and I have the css file inside `public/app.css`

Comment: Try `href='/app.css'`

Comment: @DenisCappelini  Thank's, not sure this guy is seeing my comments.. :)

Comment: Probably not hahaha

Comment: Yep this worked! Sorry I did see your comments @Keith !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. Fixed it by doing `/app.css` in my `index.pug`